# Are the same cards available for a particular arena to all players?

Tags: clash-royale

Are the cards specific for a particular arena or do they vary for each player (as some higher arena cards have a question mark on it).

If they are fixed, what cards can be earned in each arena?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All cards are the same for everyone. Every card can only be unlocked on a given arena and this doesn't vary. [Here are all the arena specific unlocks.](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Arenas) The cards can be viewed here: [troops](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Troop_Cards), [spells](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Spell_Cards) and [buildings](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Building_Cards). God knows why they wouldn't show them to us, or allow us to click on them and view their stats. My best guess is they are trying to preserve the element of surprise...

Comment: The cards that are hidden are the Legendaries and Epics.

Comment: No, actually only Legendaries are hidden

Comment: @PythonMaster Nope, epics and + are hidden. I was on 4, could only see the Wizard and the  Zap from 5, the rest was 3 question marks! Now when I'm on 5, only the legend is question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they have now removed this completely as I get no question marks in higher arenas and they show legendary cards